# Apache POI Word add field

Tags: java, apache-poi

**Background:** When using Microsoft Word one can define fields which are then being replaced with some values.

For example adding the following and then activating the field function will then display the title of the document (defined in the properties).

[image: Word field]

**Question:** is there any way to add such fields when generating my Word document with Apache POI so that the end user sees the correct values (I will also provide the values for the fields). I looked through the methods defined on the Document object but did not see anything useful. Just writing this string in the document is not going to work (kind of obvious...)

**Edit:** The XML for some field looks like this (in this case the AUTHOR of the document)

```
<w:p w:rsidRDefault="00AB5E40" w:rsidR="009B15AD">
  <w:fldSimple w:instr=" AUTHOR \* MERGEFORMAT ">
    <w:r>
      <w:rPr>
        <w:noProof/>
      </w:rPr>
      <w:t>My Name</w:t>
    </w:r>
  </w:fldSimple>
</w:p>
```

Comment: Which file format are you working with - `.doc` (HWPF) or `.docx` (XWPF)?

Comment: I prefer `.docx` (XWPF) but even HWPF would suffice if this is the only way to go..

Comment: XWPF would be easier. If you create a simple `.docx` file in Microsoft Word, with a single paragraph with a single field in it, then unzip the .docx file, what XML did Word pop into the paragraph for the field?

Comment: I updated the question with the relevant XML snippet

Comment: Good and bad news. Bad news - there's no high level POI API for this. Good news - there is a low level one! You happy with getting your hands dirty messing around with the XML and CT objects?

Comment: Well given the fact that my other option is docx4j and I am stuck with Apache POI, a low-level solution is the only way to go.

Comment: Another option is for you to write a patch to Apache POI to add the high level methods... ;-) Or at least help spec + test one!

Comment: @Gagravarr do you happen to know the low-level solution? I might be able then to contribute a patch

Comment: You'll need to create a few test files, unzip them, and look at the XML that's needed + where. Now, use the CT low-level XML classes from Apache POI, to create the same. The CT names are based on the XSD definition names, which are very close but not always identical to the XML tag names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question in case somebody has a similar problem. As Gagravarr pointed out, there is no high-level API for this but by looking at the XML structure I came up with this:

```
private static void addField(XWPFParagraph paragraph, String fieldName) {
    CTSimpleField ctSimpleField = paragraph.getCTP().addNewFldSimple();
    ctSimpleField.setInstr(fieldName + " \\* MERGEFORMAT ");
    ctSimpleField.addNewR().addNewT().setStringValue("<<fieldName>>");
}
```

Calling this method with some paragraph you have at hand and a field name will render this field in your document (either with the correct value or with << fieldName >>)

Comment: How to list and replace these fields with some dynamic value?